# Get metadata using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Your help would be greatly appreciated

I have the following code: It is suppose to get the metatags from a website:

```
function calculate() {
    // This gets the title:
    g_title = ('' + document.title + '');
    g_title_count = ('' + document.title.split(' ').length + '');
    g_title_length = ('' + document.title.length + '')
    // This checks all the MetaTags:
    g_metadata = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")[i];
    g_keywords = "test";
    if (typeof g_metadata != 'undefined') {
        if (g_metadata) {
            var i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                if (g_metadata.name == 'keywords') {
                    g_keywords[i] = (g_metadata.name[i] + g_metadata.content[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This value currently returns "test" as specified in the code above:

```
document.form1.g_keywords.value = g_keywords
```

However I need it to capture the keywords metatag, description and title.

```
<title>Test 1</title>
<meta name="keywords"content="test2" />
<meta name="description" content="test3" />
```

and then write it to a form:

```
<textarea name="g_keywords" id="g_keywords" cols="80" rows="5" onchange="calculate(this.form1)"></textarea>
```

It currently works for the `Title` but not to get the `<meta name="keywords" content="" >` tag

```
if (g_metadata.name == 'keywords') {
    g_keywords[i] = (g_metadata.name[i] + g_metadata.content[i]);
}
```

I have tried it by creating the above but are not sure how to execute it...

Please help - Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// Collect all keywords
g_metadata = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
g_keywords = []; // should be an array
var len = g_metadata.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (g_metadata[i].name == 'keywords') {
        g_keywords = g_metadata[i].content.split(",");
    }
}​
```

I think there supposed to be only one keyword `<meta>` tag, and all the keywords are listed there separated by comma.
**[[Demo](http://jsbin.com/oyafa3/)]**

Comment: Hi Galambalazs the Demo did it for me :-) Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Galambalazs how can I get the g_keywords.length to display the number of characters (if I query g_keywords.length) it gives me the number of words... g_keywords.join(',').lenght = number of characters ?

Comment: `g_keywords.join('').length` without commas, and `g_keywords.join(',').length` with commas

Answer (score 2):

You `for` loop is a bit off, you're trying to use `i` before it's created, this should be what you're after:

```
var g_keywords = [], g_description = "No description found", 
    g_metadata = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")
for (var i=0;i<=g_metadata.length;i++);{
  switch(g_metadata[i].name) {
    case 'keywords':
      g_keywords.push(g_metadata[i].content);
      break;
    case 'description':
      g_description = g_metadata[i].content;
      break;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what you're after with the keywords and metadata, it seems like you want an array for keywords and one string for description, that's what the above does.  It loops though the `<meta>` tags and if the `name` is "keywords" it pushes the `.content` onto the `g_keywords` array...if it's "description" it sets `g_description` to that tag's `content`.